# Block Vertical Format Videos On YouTube, Whether Or Not They Are Tagged As #Shorts

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, youtube

Is there an existing extension or javascript code that can detect if the video has taller vertical dimensions than its width dimension, and block them from appearing if the ratio reveals a vertical format?

I find that ALL such videos have basically worthless content, because YouTube is forcing creators to make throw-away clips, in a pathetic attempt to steal profits from TikTok by disvaluing existing YouTube.  But anyway, I want to spare my time & attention when the few channels I follow get sucked into the bad behavior.  I can't be the only guy who needs this, right?

Answer (score 0):

With youtube shorts, run an extension that detects `/short/` and changes it to `/watch/`. This won't change the actual video resolution, but sets it against a nice 16:9 -ish frame. Kind of like what [Youtube shorts-block](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-shorts-block/jiaopdjbehhjgokpphdfgmapkobbnmjp) can do, [Nebula Enhancer](https://www.reddit.com/r/watchnebula/comments/m5zydi/comment/gr3jd6n/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) might be worth exploring.

With [UBlockOrigin](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/143mdqv/code_to_block_youtube_shorts_june_2023/): there is a workaround:

```
!This line removes all the shorts videos.
youtube.com##:xpath(//ytd-rich-item-renderer[descendant::span[contains(@aria-label,"Shorts")]])
!This part removes the "New Row" object
youtube.com##ytd-rich-grid-row, #contents.ytd-rich-grid-row:style(display:contents !important;)
This part limits the number of videos per row.
youtube.com##ytd-rich-grid-renderer:style(--ytd-rich-grid-items-per-row: 6 !important;)
```

Also try commissioning your own extension using code that reads the headers of the video pointed to by the url like some of the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291388/client-side-javascript-get-video-width-height-before-upload). If they are portrait, either [stop the video load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094397/how-can-i-stop-a-video-with-javascript-in-youtube), or more drastically, [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window) the browser tab.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785841/how-to-get-video-resolution-on-browser-javascript) using [this library](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js) claims to do what you want, the application of which could end up something quite removed from just "plug and play" though.